# Why do we say kidush twice at the seder?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

At the *seder* on the first night (or two nights) of *Pesach*, we follow a particular, strict [order of operations](/a/14605):

- *Kadesh*, recite *kidush*.
- *Urchatz*, wash hands for *karpas*.
- *Karpas*, eat a vegetable.
- *Yachatz*, halve a *matza*.
- *Magid*, tell the *hagada*.
- *Rochtza*, wash hands for bread.
- *Motzi, matza*, recite the benedictions over, and eat, the *matza*.
- …

Yet *Onkelus*, in *Ki Sisa* 30:18 and again in *P'kude* 40:30, says *rochtza* means not washing hands but reciting *kidush*:

> וְעָשִׂיתָ כִּיּוֹר נְחֹשֶׁת וְכַנּוֹ נְחֹשֶׁת **לְרָחְצָה**
> וְתַעֲבֵיד כִּיּוֹרָא דִּנְחָשָׁא וּבְסִיסֵיהּ דִּנְחָשָׁא **לְקִדּוּשׁ**
>
> וַיִּתֵּן שָׁמָּה מַיִם **לְרָחְצָה**
> וִיהַב תַּמָּן מַיָּא **לְקִדּוּשׁ**

<sub>(Texts from [Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/u/u0.htm).)</sub>

Thus, according to *Onkelus*, the order is:

- *Kadesh*, recite *kidush*.
- *Urchatz*, wash hands for *karpas*.
- *Karpas*, eat a vegetable.
- *Yachatz*, halve a *matza*.
- *Magid*, tell the *hagada*.
- *Rochtza*, **recite *kidush***.
- *Motzi, matza*, recite the benedictions over, and eat, the *matza*.
- …

Thus, according to *Onkelus*, we recite *kidush* twice at the *seder*, unlike every other *Shabas* and *yom tov* evening. Why do we recite *kidush* twice?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We learn that we have to be סומך גאולה לתפילה (connect redemption and prayer) in [Brachot](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=9b&format=pdf).

We finish off Maggid with a blessing of redemption:

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ גָּאַל יִשְׂרָאֵל.

Now we must have a prayer. But if we would go right into Motzi-Matzah, we have none, as that isn't a prayer. Instead, we must look to the text of kiddush:

> וַתִּתֵּן לָנוּ ה' אֱלהֵינוּ בְּאַהֲבָה. (בשבת - שַׁבָּתות לִמְנוּחָה וּ) מועֲדִים לְשִׂמְחָה. חַגִּים וּזְמַנִּים לְשָׂשׂון.
>
> And give to us, Hashem our God, with love, seasons of happiness, festivals and times of joy.

Sounds like a request (prayer) to me!

That's why we make kiddush a second time after maggid.

As for why we need to make it a first time, we learn ([Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 271:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1469)) that kiddush should be made immediately upon returning home. In [ibid:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1469) we see additionally that one is forbidden to eat before hearing kiddush. In order to eat the karpas (strict order of operations, remember?) we must therefore make kiddush at the beginning.